# How is memory for an object allocated internally?

Tags: java, memory

I want to understand how JVM internally allocates memory. I have read that "new" bytecode instruction does this. Once the "new" instruction is executed, what kind of bookkeeping is done for the memory that is allocated on heap? Is there a way to create an instance of a class without using new (ReflectionFactory maybe)?

Answer (score 2):

*Is there a way to create an instance of a class without using new (ReflectionFactory maybe)?*

No. In Java, you create an instance with `new`.

*Once the "new" instruction is executed, what kind of bookeeping is done for the memoery that is allocated on heap?*

Java uses a garbage collector, the memory model is documented in [JLS-17.4 Memory Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) which says (in part)

> A *memory model* describes, given a program and an execution trace of that program, whether the execution trace is a legal execution of the program. The Java programming language memory model works by examining each read in an execution trace and checking that the write observed by that read is valid according to certain rules.
>
> The memory model describes possible behaviors of a program. An implementation is free to produce any code it likes, as long as all resulting executions of a program produce a result that can be predicted by the memory model.

**Edit**

As stated in the comments, there may be other instructions to create an instance without using an explicit `new`, but the instances so created still follow the specified Java memory model.

Comment: Is `Class#newInstance()` not a way to create an instance without using the new keyword? Or clone()? Both should boil down to some `native` method that implements instance creation without using the new keyword. new *keyword* though

Comment: If you create an object using new, the constructor is always called. Have a look at this - http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue175.html If there exists a way to create an object without calling constructor, then new may not be the only way.

Comment: There are at least five different ways to create objects, and `new` is only one of them. `Class.newInstance(),` de-serialization, `clone(),` and JNI. Just off the top of my head. There could certainly be more.

Comment: @EJP So that means there is some common native code that actually allocates memory for an object correct?

Comment: @karmanaut Yes, `new` compiles into a [certain bytecode](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-bytecode-fundamentals-using-objects-and-calling-methods/), the Java Virtual Machine is responsible to take that and do what the spec demands. The Java Memory Model defines for example how the memory has to behave when observed from your java program. Different JVMs can implement their memory management differently as long as it is compatible with those specs. http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-jvm-internals/

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance with Class.newInstance() or if a class is Cloneable you can create an instance (copy of another object) using Object.clone().